# How do I remove the "mobile" service in google apps

Tags: google-apps

As Google provide no support for removing a free google apps account, I'm hoping someone here can help. I've followed these instructions:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/1257646?hl=en

However, I am unable to remove one service which is the "Mobile" service. There is no option to remove this service.

Is there a way to turn off this service and so delete my free google apps account?

Comment: AFAIK, mobile CANNOT be deleted, but it's a service, not an app.  If you have all the users out of your account and all the other services, you should be able to continue in the process.

Comment: Many thanks, you are correct, after reading your comment I went through the marketplace and found two services. Once deleted, I was then able to delete my account. Many thanks!

Comment: Very welcome :) I'll add that as an answer in case someone else falls on this :)

Answer (score 0):

The "Mobile" Service is impossible to delete, but it doesn't stop you from deleting your account. As long as you don't have users or some OTHER service enabled, you can delete your account easily :).